# C++ - Unsigned integers

Tags: c++, integer, unsigned

I have the following program written in C++:

The problem with this program is that if the user inputs a negative number, it is NOT caught by the line `if(!cin)`.  I thought that unsigned integers can NOT accept negative numbers.  Then why if I enter a negative number to size, it is NOT caught by `if(!cin)` and the program continues execution with no error messages?

I cannot make use of `if(size < 0)`.  I want to show how unsigned integers can solve the problem of negative input.

Comment: Can't you input the data in a signed integer, make a check and then assign it to an unsigned one?

Comment: I am working on a project investigating how certain security vulnerabilities can be mitigated.  Currently, I am investigating integer overflows and read that if you are programming and you don't require negative numbers, you can make use of unsigned integers and the problem is solved.

Comment: However, if I try to input a negative number in the unsigned integer size, it is still accepted :s

Comment: You are mistaking two different things. It's true that an unsigned number can never have a negative value. It is not true that a negative number is not a valid external representation of an unsigned number. So given a 32-bit unsigned integer "-1" will be read as the value 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: @john Thanks John.  Now I understand.  So unsigned numbers can take negative numbers, however these will always be represented as positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between unsigned and signed integers on most platforms is a sign-bit ... other than that, the actual binary value is the same, it's just interpreted two different ways depending on the sign-ness of the type that the binary value represents.  So you can definitely "represent" a negative value input as a unsigned value ... it won't be re-interpreted as that value, but it can definitely be input as that value without an error being set on the stream.

Comment: Is there a way to catch this?  Is there a way to determine if the user entered a negative number to an unsigned number at the input stage?

Comment: Read a string, see if it starts with a '-', if not convert to a number.

Comment: Yeah, the "negative" unsigned value re-interpreted as a signed value will be `UINT_MAX + 1` minus the "negative" unsigned value.  For instance, if the user input `-1`, then `UINT_MAX + 1 - 1` would be `UINT_MAX` ... so `UINT_MAX` is the binary representation of `-1` in unsigned form.

Answer (score 1):

Not a c++ guru or anything but, have you tried using `cin.fail()` instead of !cin and clear out your buffer with `cin.clear()`
[deeper explaination](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/)

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ allow you to assign a negative value to an object of an unsigned type. The result is the original value reduced modulo `2^n`, where `n` is the size of the unsigned type. So, for example, `unsigned i = -1;` initializes `i` to `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

The check  `if(!cin)` will only indicate that *nothing* was read, like the end of a file.

An `unsigned` integer doesn't *force* the input to be positive; it just means that the value will always be *interpreted* as positive (see [sign bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit)), which can have dramatic effects if the number is in fact negative.

Your best bet is probably to input a signed integer and then test in your code whether it is positive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from entering negative numbers, take input as a signed number and check that it's equal to or greater than zero.

The standard basically says that when you try to assign a number to an integral type that is outside of the range of the type, multiples of the magnitude of the type will be added or subtracted until the value is within the range.

It just so happens that with values expressed as 2-s complement and within the ranges of signed and unsigned ints, this means that the exact same bit pattern will be assigned to any value.  Negative one has a bit pattern of all ones, which translates to the highest possible value for the unsigned int, and is equivalent to `-1 + 232` or the original value plus the magnitude of an unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use a larger signed integral type.

```
long long n = -1;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> n;

if( !cin.good() )
    cout << "Not a valid number." << endl;
else if( n > UINT_MAX )
    cout << "Overflow, value is more than UINT_MAX." << endl;
else if( n < 0 )
    cout << "Negative, value is less than 0." << endl;
else {
    unsigned int m = (unsigned int)n;
    cout << "Valid unsigned int was input: " << m << "." << endl;
}
```